# Summary of the last decade of garbage collection?

Tags: garbage-collection

I've been reading through the Jones & Lins book on garbage collection, which was published in 1996.

Obviously, the computing world has changed dramatically since then: multicore, out-of-order  chips with large caches, and even larger main memory in desktops. The world has also more-or-less settled on the x86 and ARM microarchitectures for most consumer-facing systems.

**What have the most significant advances been since the seminal book was published?**

I'm looking in particular for pointers to papers, algorithms, dissertations, and the like, representing advances in both the theory & practice of garbage collection.

Comment: *"I'm looking in particular for pointers to papers, algorithms, dissertations, and the like, representing advances in both the theory & practice of garbage collection."* - Asking on StackOverflow is the WRONG way to do a literature survey (or "research" in general).  PhD candidates - do NOT follow this example.

Comment: For what it's worth, I wasn't a PhD candidate (or any other sort of researcher) at the time I posed the question. The date of posting is also relevant -- many years ago, StackOverflow was the sort of place an outsider could seek to tap into deep knowledge pools on broad topics like this. I agree SO isn't a substitute for a literature survey, but the "proper" survey at the time would have meant getting access to (not trivial for those without university affiliation!) and reading ~200 papers. That's an entirely different league of interest and commitment than represented by my post.

Comment: For what it is worth, a question like this were never really appropriate here because it was and is basically impossible to answer adequately.  Look at the answers you actually got.   Over the 3 years that the question was open.  That ... of course ... is the reason why this is not a worthwhile way of doing research.  It does not work.  (And, for what it is worth, what you were doing was research, whether you want to call it that or something else.)

Comment: I can't recall exactly, but I might have added that comment because some other student used your Question as an example of why it is "OK" to ask questions like this.  Frankly, I think it should be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, most advances on garbage collection techniques in the last decade were on the "practical" side: algorithms were known, but some considerable tuning was performed with regards to multi-core systems and observed usage patterns. A substantial part of that research was done by Sun and IBM, in the context of Java (it is striking that most of the usage pattern analyses presented in the Jones & Lins book is about Lisp and its singly-linked lists; nowadays papers talk about Java). The G1 algorithm from Sun is built upon older ideas which are all in the Jones & Lins book -- but the people at Sun (now Oracle) worked hard to find out which combination was most efficient.

There was also much research on distributed garbage collection -- how to GC-manage data objects which are scattered over distinct systems, within the usual challenging conditions of distributed computing: network is slow, nodes may not be equivalent to each other, some nodes may fail. The overall conclusion seems to be that it does not work (there was much more *research* than *findings*). Limited versions with reference counting (for references to objects located on another system) have been implemented (e.g. in Java's RMI) and appear to work in contexts where there is no cycle of references across nodes.

Answer (score 3):

**GC Advancements on the JVM:**

G1 of the JVM seems to bring some new improvements on the table (for the JVM atleast)

> G1 is a “server-style” GC and has the
>   following attributes.
>
> **Parallelism and Concurrency.** G1 takes
>   advantage of the parallelism that
>   exists in hardware today. It uses all
>   available CPUs (cores, hardware
>   threads, etc.) to speed up its
>   “stop-the-world” pauses when an
>   application's Java threads are stopped
>   to enable GC. It also works
>   concurrently with running Java threads
>   to minimize whole-heap operations
>   during stop-the-world pauses.
>
> **Generational.** Like the other HotSpot
>   GC's, G1 is generational, meaning it
>   treats newly-allocated (aka young)
>   objects and objects that have lived
>   for some time (aka old) differently.
>   It concentrates garbage collection
>   activity on young objects, as they are
>   the ones most likely to be
>   reclaimable, while visiting old
>   objects infrequently. For most Java
>   applications, generational garbage
>   collection has major efficiency
>   advantages over alternative schemes.
>
> **Compaction.** Unlike CMS, G1 performs
>   heap compaction over time. Compaction
>   eliminates potential fragmentation
>   problems to ensure smooth and
>   consistent long-running operation.
>
> **Predictability.** G1 is expected to be
>   more predictable than CMS. This is
>   largely due to the elimination of
>   fragmentation issues that can
>   negatively affect stop-the-world pause
>   times in CMS. Additionally, G1 has a
>   pause prediction model that, in many
>   situations, allows it to often meet
>   (or rarely exceed) a pause time
>   target.

[G1 Link](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/g1_intro.jsp)

HotSpot 6 Seems to have numerous [garbage collectors](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html#available_collectors) you can choose from.

Comment: I'd like to point out that today the JVM is not for the Java Language only, but also for other programming languages like Scala, Clojure, Python and Ruby. So the GC improvements do not touch Java alone.

Comment: Concurrent, generational, and compacting garbage collecting algorithms all predate Jones & Lin.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I came across earlier and just remembered it now :

**FPGA-Aware Garbage Collection in Java**

> In this paper we present novel work
>   enabling a HW component to actually
>   create and hold references to
>   dynamically allocated objects. Since
>   HW components can now hold objects,
>   the Java garbage collector needs to be
>   made aware of the existence of these
>   object references in order to nd all
>   objects that are still in use.

[Link to PDF Paper](http://buytaert.net/files/fpl05-paper.pdf)